# Turn deserialized/denormalized entity into doctrine proxy?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am persisting some entities to a json based db using the symfony serializer.
When retrieving them from the json db they are deserialized again.
Not all fields are serialized before persisting to the json db.

Is it possible to turn deserialized entities into doctrine proxies, so their relationships can be queried?

### Example

`App\Entity\Employer` and `App\Entity\Employee` (Employee --ManyToOne--> Employer), Employer is not null on Employee.

The relationship is not serialized before persisting `Employee` to json db.

```php
$documentFromJsonDb = ...;

/** @var App\Entity\Employee */
$employee = $this->normalizer->denormalize($documentFromJsonDb, 'json');
$employee->getEmployer(); // This returns null :( not making a db call

$employee = MagicMethod($employee);
$employee->getEmployer() // This returns an instance of App\Entity\Employer :)
```

I had a look into the `Doctrine\Common\Proxy\ProxyGenerator` so far.

Is there a non hacky way to do this without too much overhead?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to `merge` your decoded entity to be able to use Doctrine abilities ?

Take a look on this documentation of Doctrine : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities

It would be something like :

```php
$documentFromJsonDb = ...;

/** @var App\Entity\Employee */
$employee = $this->normalizer->denormalize($documentFromJsonDb, 'json');
$mergedEmployee = $em->merge($employee);

$mergedEmployee->getEmployer(); // Would this work ? :)
```

Please tell me if it will do the job ? I did not have time to test it

Comment: Note that although this might work *for now*, `merge` is [deprecated](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/a6577b89a2b028b79550ef58d9f272debdd75da4/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L712) and set to be removed in doctrine 3. You can read about the reasoning for this [in this github issue](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/8461).

Comment: @msg Thank you for pointing this out. It seems most people would use merge to update the merged entity afterwards. In my case the motivation was to save some db calls, by at least using the data delivered by the json db. Merging would have been convenient so I can easily access nested objects in case they are needed somewhere on the frontend. What beberlei described in the post seems no different to me from fetching them again via doctrine using the entities ID, which is what I've done in the past.

Comment: @Andy Well, yes, even the `merge` operation will still result on db queries to hydrate the objects. The concern, as [raised by dbrumann](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/8461#issuecomment-809330881) later in the discussion, is that the entity *could* have changed before deserializing, resulting in a dirty entity. And, as per the deprecation, that code will break when migrating to 3.